# JPA EclipseLink Parent Child

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many, entity-relationship

I am currently using 2 classes that have a OneToMany relation. One class contains catalogs (you can think of it as book); an other class contains template (you can think of it as pages). In this scenario, one template can belong only to one catalog hence I used the OneToMany relation.

My application goes very well until I restart the service. It is currently running on Hana Cloud Platform under MaxDB. I am using JPA and eclipselink (I used @AdditionalCriteria to manage my multi-tenancy as the multi-tenancy offered by JPA does not allow me to make queries on multiple tenants).

Here is an extract of my code for the Catalog:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Catalog")
@AdditionalCriteria("(:adminAccess = 1 or this.customerId=:customerId) AND (:allStatus = 1 or this.statusRecord = :statusRecord)")


public class Catalog implements Serializable {  
private static final long   serialVersionUID    = -3906948030586841482L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long                id;

[...]

@OneToMany(cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = false, fetch = EAGER, mappedBy = "catalog")
private Set<Template>       templates           = new HashSet<Template>();

[...]

public void setTemplate(Template template) {
    this.templates.add(template);
}
}
```

The code for Template is the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Template")
@AdditionalCriteria("(:adminAccess = 1 or this.customerId=:customerId) AND (:allStatus = 1 or this.statusRecord = :statusRecord)")
public class Template implements Serializable {
    private static final long       serialVersionUID    = 5268250318899275624L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long                    id;

    [...]

    @ManyToOne(cascade = ALL, fetch = EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "catalog_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Catalog                 catalog;

    public void setCatalog(Catalog catalog) {
        this.catalog = catalog;

        if(!catalog.getTemplate().contains(this))
            catalog.getTemplate().add(this);
    }
}
```

In my Servlet, I use only the Catalog to make operations. If I have to save a template, I read it from the catalog, make the modifications in the template and persist the catalog.

It works very well until I restart my service.

The catalog does not have any references to the templates anymore BUT the template still have a reference to the catalog it used to belong to.

Can you please point me into the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "The catalog does not have any references to the templates anymore" - is the set `templates` empty? And if yes, how do you know that "the template still have a reference to the catalog it used to belong to."?

Comment: Yep, the set templates is empty in the catalog entity but in the template entity I can see the catalog entity. I have the impression it is because of the close of the entity factory manager (on destroy of the servlet, I close{} the entity manager and factory manager)

Comment: Interestingly... when I remove @AdditionalCriteria, everything works very well.